# Unicity of quadratic equation solution

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

I have the following equation:

$$ R(x\otimes x)=x$$

Where $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a nonnegativ vector ($x_i\geq0$) with $||x||_1=1 \quad$ ($\sum_1^n x_i=1$) and $R\in M_{n\times n^2}$ is a nonnegative matrix with $\sum_i R_{ij}=1$.

$\otimes$ stands for kronecker product

Is the solution unique?

Comment: Yes. Split $R$ into square matrices, then invoke the Perron-Frobenius theorem.

Comment: I'm not sure that it works, you are using, if I understood the proof, Perron Frobenius on a x dependent marix, $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i R_i$ so this prove unicity of $x$ for $x$ fixed.

Comment: I sadly found a counterexample